# angular 7+: ngbDropdown menu collapse instead of popover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngb dropdown to show a list of users on the screen. When a user clicks on a dropdown it shows the user details form.

The **problem** is, this form pops up over the other users and content. I **need** the user details to **collapse** instead of **popover**.

I tried putting aria-haspopup=false but that doesn't do anything, in fact it's still showing as true in inspector, so I am a bit confused on what it does and how to achieve this now? I am thinking to use something like data-toggle and collapse as in navbar toggler, but not sure how to implement this properly in ngbDropdown menu....

[image link for desired result](https://ibb.co/3dB8FCP)[1](https://ibb.co/3dB8FCP)

```
<div ngbDropdown *ngFor="let user of users" class="user-list">
    <a ngbDropdownToggle id="dropdownForm" role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName }} </a>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownForm">
      <userForm></userForm>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description/image you shared, it looks like you need an accordion, not a pop-over... because accordion has the collapsible effect, while dropdown would always be pop-over

relevant **HTML**:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc2="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" [closeOthers]="true">
  <ngb-panel  *ngFor="let user of users; let idx = index" class="user-list" >
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle >
      <span  (click)='toggleAccordion(idx)'>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName }}</span>
      <span class='stickToRight' (click)='toggleAccordion(idx)' style='float:right'> 
        <!-- ... {{idx}} - {{user.opened }} -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="user.opened">
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!user.opened">
        <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>
        </ng-container>
      </span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <!-- <userForm></userForm> -->
      <input type='text' placeholder="first Name" value="{{user.firstName}}" />  <br/>
      <input type='text' placeholder="last Name" value="{{user.lastName}}" /> <br/>
      <input type='text' placeholder="Age" /> <br/>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-basic',
  templateUrl: './accordion-basic.html',
  styles: [`
  .stickToRight{position: absolute; right: 30px;}
  `]
})
export class NgbdAccordionBasic {
  users = [
    { firstName: 'fName 1', lastName: 'lName 1', opened: false },
    { firstName: 'fName 2', lastName: 'lName 2', opened: false },
    { firstName: 'fName 3', lastName: 'lName 3', opened: false },
    { firstName: 'fName 4', lastName: 'lName 4', opened: false },
    { firstName: 'fName 5', lastName: 'lName 5', opened: false }
  ];

  resetOthers(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
      if (i !== index) {
        this.users[i].opened = false;
      }
    }
  }

  toggleAccordion(index) {
    if (this.users[index].opened == false) {
      this.users[index].opened = true;
      this.resetOthers(index);
    } else {
      this.users[index].opened = false;
      this.resetOthers(index);
    }
  }
}
```

**update**: In light of questioner's comment below

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzjkdk)

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me out to accordion. The reason I went for dropdown, because I was able to target ::after class to add that caret on the right. Any ideas how to add that dropdown caret into accordion?